# Sinon spy callCount returns 0

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I can't seem to get my test working. I have a simple mixin like so:

```
export const mixin = superclass => class mixin extends superclass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('do-it', this.doIt);
  }

  doIt() {
    console.log('did it');
  }
};
```

And a simple test as well:

```
describe('mixin', () => {
  it('should call doIt', () => {
    class TestElement extends mixin(HTMLElement) {}
    customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);

    const el = new TestElement();
    const spy = sinon.spy(el, 'doIt');

    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('do-it'));

    expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nbuLhvkd/

It logs `did it` but the spy's `callCount` value is `0`. If I do `const spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');`, the spy's `callCount` is `1`. What's the correct way of spying for instance methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `TestElement.prototype` for spying and also moved it before instantiating `new TestElement();`. It now works but can someone explain why?

```
describe('Sinon examples', () => {
  it('logs test on do-it', () => {
    class TestElement extends mixin(HTMLElement) {}
    customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);

    const spy = sinon.spy(TestElement.prototype, 'doIt');
    const el = new TestElement();

    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('do-it'));

    expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h0f9Le16/

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your 'dispatchEvent' call is asynchronous, therefore the callCount is indeed 0 since it is executed synchronously.
Otherwise your syntax is good - as your test on console call prooved.

Comment: I dont know what 'superclass' is, and I might be wrong, but given the behavior you observed thats the most logical explanation for me :)